# Scrape a word document and store it in the database using PHP

Tags: php

I would like to open a word document, read the document and scrape the data to store it in a database. Is there any tool that we can use? E.g. If we upload the resume I have to take education and work experience from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you should have a look at [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) to access the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Martin PHPWord heps to convert the php file to word document or pdf , but I am trying to read the word document and store in the database

Comment: PHPWord is "A pure PHP library for reading and writing word processing documents". You should have a look at their developers documentation: http://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ 
Storing the data you extracted from the document into a database is a next and independent step.

Comment: PHPWord doesn't just write word files, it can ___read___ them as well!